# Prove if $\lim_{x\to\ c} \ f'(x) = K$ then $f'(c) = K$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Suppose $f: (0, 1) \rightarrow {\rm I\!R}$ is continuous, with $c \in (0, 1)$, and suppose that $f'$ exists $\forall x \in (0, 1)$\{$c$}. **Prove** that if
$\lim_{x\to\ c} \ f'(x) = K$ then $f'(c) = K$.

$$\lim_{x\to\ c} \ f'(x) = K \Rightarrow \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 \text{ such that } |f'(x) - K| < \epsilon \text{ for } x \in (c-\delta, c+\delta)$$

Since $f$ is continuous and differentiable on the open interval we can use the Mean Value Theorem on $[x, c]$ where $x \in (c-\delta, c)$.

So $\exists x_1 \in (x, c)$ such that $f'(x_1) = \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}$.

By our limit definition $|f'(x_1) - K| = |\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} - K| < \epsilon$.

$$\Rightarrow \left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} - K\right| < \epsilon \text{ for } x \in (c-\delta, c)$$

We can use the MVT again on $[c, x]$ where $x \in (c, c+\delta)$, find an $x_2 \in (c, c+\delta)$ and get similar result.

$$\Rightarrow \left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} - K\right| < \epsilon \text{ for } x \in (c-\delta, c+\delta)$$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to\ c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} = K$$

$$\Rightarrow f'(c) = K$$

I'm not sure that I did this right - I'm not too comfortable with proofs yet (especially unfamiliar with using the MVT in proofs). I didn't use the fact that the domain of f is (0,1) which is concerning.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right approach.

You only need to use the MVT once:

Suppose you have chosen $\epsilon, \delta $ as above. If
we take $|h| < \delta$ then for some $\xi \in [c,c+h]$ we have
$|{f(c+h) -f(c) \over h }-K| = |f'(\xi)-K|  < \epsilon$.

Comment: I think his concern was that one needs a generalized version of the interval if $h<0$. He probably doesn't have that. (Did not downvote btw.)

Comment: @LeBtz: I glossed over that entirely, I believe you are correct.

Comment: @LeBtz: Thanks, I know who the downvoter is (at least the userid). This one is justifiable, at least.

Comment: Yeah I used it twice because $[c, c + h]$ doesn't fit our convention for writing intervals if $h < 0$.

Comment: @antsatsui: Your answer makes perfect sense then. I use the notation $[x,y]$ to mean all points on and in between $x,y$, so it has no sign, as such.

Comment: Is there any reason that problem specified $f$ on $(0,1)$? It's odd that they would give unnecessary information.

Comment: @antsatsui: I can't think of a reason since they specify $c \in (0,1)$ anyway. Perhaps to ensure that an unambiguous two-sided limit exists?